# Sharepoint Designer 2010 workflow - item level permissions

Tags: permissions, list-item

I have created a relatively complex approval workflow (using sharepoint designer 2010 workflow for a sharepoint 2013 site/list).

it is a an approval workflow that routes list items (created by form) to appropriate approvers by region and other logic.  What I am trying to do is set list item level permissions based on the approval workflow status of the item.  Specifically once the list item is created I do not want it to be edited until the workflow is complete (either fully approved or rejected).  So once the work flow is complete the user who created the item can once again contribute.  So While approval workflow is pending I want the users to have Read access, and when its complete they can have contribute access.

I have tried to add an impersonation step via workflow to replace list item permissions based on status.  It seems to work where when the item is created that the appropriate users will have view only access to the item.  However, when the item is rejected it is not re-triggering and giving the user contribute access (the item can still not be edited after rejected).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the impersonation step, use the "**Inherit List Item Parent Permissions**" action to set the permission back to what it was by default.

For example, you can add an action like:

If current item approval status equals "approved" or "rejected", Inherit List Item Parent Permissions.